# How to convert SQL to EF linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am converting a SQL query with 2 table joins to an Entity Framework linq query in a .NET 6 application.

The SQL query as I mentioned is joining 2 tables on this condition:

```
substr(a.anystring, 0, length(a.anystring) - (length(a.anystring) - instr(a.anystring, '_') + 1))
```

I changed it to EF linq code as shown here, but I am getting an error saying unable to translate `IndexOf` to SQL:

```
anystring.Substring(0, anystring.Length - (anystring.IndexOf('_') + 1))
```

Error:

> Additional information: Translation of method 'string.IndexOf' failed

Comment: What database provider? What EF version? In EF Core, C# methods are dependent on the database provider for the translations that are supported.

Comment: It is Oracle. EF version 6.4.4.

Comment: I assume you are using ODP.Net? Can you try `IndexOf("_")` instead?

Comment: @PowerMouse The error is not an exception. It is an EF error stating that the C# method doesn't have a translation to SQL. It is not an Oracle or SQL issue.

Comment: @NetMage, yes that was the issue, I had to use double quotes. Do you want to write it as the answer and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ODP.Net the EF Canonical Function translation for `String.IndexOf` apparently only supports the overload that takes a `string` parameter (unfortunately, poorly documented by Oracle).

Using the `String.IndexOf` overload that takes a `string` parameter should translate:

```
anystring.Substring(0, anystring.Length - (anystring.IndexOf("_") + 1))
```